# history in implementation of shell get segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, shell, singly-linked-list

So I wrote some code to implement the shell (Linux, GCC, C language) and it all works but from some reason the code crashes when I added the history option:
It really doesn't (the other code) so I'll put here only what you need.

The problem is when I type `quit` after one old command that need to be saved in the history and when I type quit it just crushes with segmentation fault (core dumped).

The history is saved in a structure of a linked list, string of command and the node for the next node, also I saved the head in the main. The point is that I want to save only 15 last commands, and I don't care about the others, so every time I want to print the list I just moved on the first 15 nodes in the loop.

When I debugged with GDB I saw that the line the code crashes is the line after he add the first command the the history but the current line is really not related to the history:
main:

```
int main()
{
    history_ll* top;
    char userInput [CHOICE_LENGTH];
    char buff[PATH_MAX];
    int flag=1;
    cmdLine * head; 
    while (flag)
    {
        getcwd(buff, PATH_MAX); 
        printf("%s:~$ ",buff);
        fgets(userInput,MAX_INPUT, stdin);
        userInput[strlen(userInput)-1]=0;
        historyAdder(userInput,&top);
        if(strcmp(userInput,QUIT_OPTION)==0)    //segmentation fault here!
        {
            flag=0;
        }
        else
        {
            //doesn't matter
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the historyAdder looks like this:

```
void historyAdder(const char *command,history_ll** top)
{
    history_ll* node;
    strcpy(node->command,command);
    node->command[strlen(command)]=0;
    if(historyLength!=0)
    {
        node->next= *top;
    }
    else
    {
        node->next= NULL;
    }
    *top = node;
    historyLength++;
}
```

**NOTE: historyLength is a global variable**

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct history_ll{
    char command[CHOICE_LENGTH];
    struct history_ll *next;
}history_ll;
```

Thank you helpers!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two important issues in this code.
One is that buffer length might ne too short when you read from stdin:
definition:

```
char userInput [CHOICE_LENGTH];
```

but usage is:

```
fgets(userInput,MAX_INPUT, stdin);
```

You should use same buffer size or assert `MAX_INPUT` is less or equal `CHOICE_LENGTH`.

Second, you trigger undefined behavior by dereferencing uninitialised pointer here:

```
void historyAdder(const char *command,history_ll** top)
{
    history_ll* node;
    strcpy(node->command,command);  /* bad... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here (and in the lines following)

```
void historyAdder(const char *command,history_ll** top)
{
  history_ll* node;
  strcpy(node->command,command);
  ...
```

the code dereferences an uninitialised pointer: `node` Doing so invokes UB and mostly likely crashes the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* your problem:

```
char userInput [CHOICE_LENGTH];
...
fgets(userInput,MAX_INPUT, stdin);
```

Unless `CHOICE_LENGTH` is greater than or equal to `MAX_INPUT`, `fgets` can write past the end of the `userInput` array, which will corrupt memory, leading to a crash.  However, since you did not show a *complete* program that I could compile for myself and watch crash, I can't be sure.

Two pieces of advice for you:

- You're on Linux, so you have [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).  Use it instead of `fgets` and you won't have to worry about input buffer sizes.
- Whenever you have a program that is crashing with segmentation faults, the first thing you reach for should be [valgrind](https://valgrind.org). Very often, valgrind will reveal that the *real* bug is nowhere near where you thought it was.